# Swift Closure Completion Handler

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler, completion

I have a function right now that is determining the hide behavior of a UILabel: `func shouldHideLabel() -> Bool`.

I need to retrieve data from a web request to determine whether or not to hide this label, so inside of `shouldHideLabel()` I'm making a call to a function `func webRequestDataIsValid() -> Bool`.

`webRequestDataIsValid()` is doing a web request with a closure, returning an object, and the object has a variable `isValid` on it, which is returning true or false.

My goal is to wait on this `isValid` flag to be returned to me, return from `webRequestDataIsValid` with true or false, and then use that return value to return from the original `shouldHideLabel` function.

I'm using a completion handler inside of `shouldHideLabel` to wait on the data from `webRequestDataIsValid`, but I'm not sure how to wait on returning inside of `shouldHideLabel` for my closure to finish. It seems like you can't return from a function while inside of a closure.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that your web request will contain a completionBlock,
try this:

```
func webRequestDataIsValid(completion: @escaping ((Bool) ->Void)) {
    whateverYourRequestMethod.response { httpResponse in
        let isValid = true // retrieve your boolean
        completion(isValid)
    )
}
```